# makefile linking fortran library to a C program

Tags: c, makefile, linker, fortran

I'm trying to build a makefile in order to compile a C program and then link it to a fortran library called MUMPS (that also needs blas and pthread libraries). So my idea was to compile by the gcc and then link by the gfortran. here's what I got.

```
ROOT = $(addprefix $(PWD), /)
BUILDS_DIR = $(addprefix $(ROOT), builds/)
SRCS_DIR   = $(addprefix $(ROOT), src/)
INCS_DIR   = $(addprefix $(ROOT), src/)
OBJS_DIR   = $(addprefix $(SRCS_DIR), objects/)
LIBS_DIR   =

MUMPS_DIR      = $(MUMPS_ROOT)
MUMPS_INCS_DIR = $(addprefix $(MUMPS_DIR), /include)
MUMPS_LIB_DIR  = $(addprefix $(MUMPS_DIR), /lib)
MUMPS_MPI_DIR  = $(addprefix $(MUMPS_ROOT), /libseq)

CC       = gcc -c
CFLAGS   = -O3 -DTRILIBRARY
INCLUDES = -I$(INCS_DIR) -I$(MUMPS_INCS_DIR)

FL       = gfortran -o
LFLAGS   = -L$(LIBS_DIR) -L$(MUMPS_LIB_DIR) -L$(MUMPS_MPI_DIR)
CLIBS    = -lm
FLIBS    = -lblas
LDLIBS   = -lpthread

MUMPS_LIBS = -ldmumps -ldmumps_seq -lmumps_common -lmumps_common_seq -lpord -lpord_seq -lmpiseq

LIBS = $(CLIBS) $(FLIBS) $(LDFLIBS) $(MUMPS_LIBS)
```

while the rules are

```
default: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    @echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Compile successfully! ***\n" ;
    $(FL) $(BUILDS_DIR)$@ $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS) \
        $(OBJS)
    @echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Linking complete! ***\n"

$(OBJS): $(OBJS_DIR)%.o : $(SRCS_DIR)%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) \
        $<\
        -o $@
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and it gives me as an error

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldmumps
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldmumps_seq
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmumps_common
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmumps_common_seq
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpord
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpord_seq

where am I wrong?

Update: I actually found the bug of my makefile. In the linking step, I was calling the libraries before the objects.o and apparently this is not acceptable. In fact, it was trying to link libraries to some object files that I haven't called yet. if I put $(LIBS) after $(OBJS) everything works out. Hope this could be useful to someone else.

Comment: That's the output from linking with `$(FL)`?

Comment: could you add something like `echo $(MUMPS_LIB_DIR)` in your target, to check if it is set correctly ?

Comment: sorry for the delay. yes, i checked the path and it's the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Linker errors of the form

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldmumps

indicate that the library you asked to be linked is not present in the library search path.

Ensure that the MUMPS development libraries installed.  Sometimes development components are packaged and/or installed separately from runtime components.  The development libraries will have names of the form `libdmumps.so` or `libdmumps.a`, with nothing extra appended to the end.

If the dev libraries are installed and have names corresponding to your link options, then it must be the case that they are located somewhere that is not on the linker's default search path.  That wouldn't be too unusual.  For example, the MUMPS libraries may be installed in /usr/lib/mumps, /usr/lib64/mumps, or /opt/mumps/lib, none of which will be searched by default.  If the libraries exist, but their directory is not on the default search path, then you must add a `-L/path/to/library/dir` link option before all the `-ldmumps` etc..

In any case, if your main program is written in C, then you should use a C linker driver (gcc for you) to link it.  Your C code will likely have to refer to Fortran functions via mangled names, and it will have to use argument conventions appropriate to calling the desired functions.  You cannot get around that by choice of linker, because the structure of all your function calls is set up by the compiler, not the linker.

Comment: Actually I checked and mumps is not in any of the three directories you mentioned but it's well installed and the paths are right.

Comment: besides, I also tried to change the linker by gcc -o but I got the same error

Comment: I found the error but I got now a new one...
The problem was in the variable LIBS_DIR that was empty and the make got lost in the linking phase. however now I got this error:
`system_implicit_solver.c:(.text+0x16ab): undefined reference to `dmumps_c'`
and by googling a while it seems due to a wrong linking with the BLAS. I should use the BLAS of the system. so I did:
`LIBS_DIR   = /usr/lib64`
but I still receive the same error. so maybe I'm wrong again.

Comment: The three possible library locations I listed were reasonably likely examples, not an exhaustive list of the possibilities.  When you say "the paths are right" what do you mean?  Where is libdmumps.so (or libdmumps.a) located?

Comment: If all the libraries you are trying to use are located in the linker's default search path, then you should not need to set make variables to get it to find them.  Is it possible, though, that you have the *wrong* libraries?  In particular, is it possible that your libraries are compiled for 32-bit hardware, but you're trying to build a 64-bit application?

Comment: about the path, yes, I meant the path where these libraries are located.
the issue of 32-bit version I dunno. I installed this mumps library in this current machine so it should be already 64-bit. As I said, googling I found this (http://opensees.berkeley.edu/community/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=60958) and it sounds pretty much like my problem but I still dunno how to sort it out.

Comment: If MUMPS is indeed written in Fortran then it is likely that your C code needs to refer to its functions via mangled names and appropriate calling conventions, as I wrote earlier.  Possibly, though, a function with a name such as `dmumps_c` is a C wrapper function that handles such details for you.  If that's the case, and your C code uses only such wrapper functions, then my recommendation to link with gcc becomes an imperative.  Also, it may be in that case that the C interface functions are in a separate library that you must add to your library list.

Comment: thanks a lot! indeed dmumps_c seems to be a C wrapper function from C to Fortran language. However, in mumps library they put an example to link a C file to mumps and they compile by gcc the C file but then they link it by f95 to mumps. anyway, I tried and it seems to work for both linkers.